# PHP PDO Select statement not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

New to mysql and VERY new to PDO - But am trying to learn with lots of tutorials.

I am trying to grab an entry in the database that corresponds to the users ID and then use that to echo out the username, etc on a profile page.

```
$stmt = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM clients WHERE id = 42');
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // Content here...

echo $results['firstname'];
```

This is giving me an **error** that the **firstname** is **undefined** - what am I doing wrong here?

Working off this tutorial: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change it with:

```
$results = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
```

as your are requesting a single row from your database and not an array with rows

```
PDOStatement::fetchAll — Returns an array containing all of the result set rows
PDOStatement::fetch — Fetches the next row from a result set
```

Comment: With respect, how would that change anything? You just changed it from a fetchall to a fetch...?

Comment: This actually fixed it. I am just researching now the difference between Fetch and fetchall

Comment: Wow, i'm actually shocked. +1 for wowing me. @mcflause, I would also recommend checking out prepared statements. Very useful.

Comment: Ah, so $results[0]['firstname'] would have worked. Gotcha. @mcflause, checkout echo print_r($results), it will show everything in a specific array. Really awesome for troubleshooting.

Comment: Yes, it would have worked, but he needs to know what fetchAll and fetch do, am I right ?

Comment: MihaiIorga Thanks for the help, this fixes it and I learnt now about fetch vs fetchall. @Jonathan I will be looking up prepared statements for sure. Thanks!